# How to navigate specific tag in beautiful soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

i want to navigate specific tag on website. on this website there is few tags that are same like this 
and i want to navigate only one of them.
every time i run code i am getting different output.

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib

source = urllib.urlopen("https://taripebi.ge/%E1%83%91%E1%83%94%E1%83%9C%E1%83%96%E1%83%98%E1%83%9C%E1%83%98%E1%83%A1-%E1%83%A4%E1%83%90%E1%83%A1%E1%83%94%E1%83%91%E1%83%98").read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

for paragraph in soup.find('div', style = "width: 40%;/* float: left; */"):
    print(paragraph)
```

Comment: maybe you can concretise your query so it will find only one element?

Comment: but how can i do this? :d

Comment: you can do this using css selector  or xpath selector

Comment: Most of the paragraphs that are 'div' are probably inheriting from that css. Open F12 and then click the arrow on top left, select the element you are looking for with it and right click on the line -> Copy -> Copy CSS Selector or XPath

Comment: all of them style is ```"width: 40%;/* float: left; */"``` https://imgur.com/a/F0fZsIz

Comment: up⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: "I want to navigate to one of them" -- a specific one or a random one? If you need a specific one, please tell us what makes if different from the other ``div`` tags with ``style="width: 40%;/* float: left; */"``

Comment: specific one, all of them style is same

Comment: Then by what criteria do you know which one you are looking for? What makes it __different__ from the other tags that have the same ``style``?

Comment: that one have different string

Comment: the tag contents between ``<tag>`` and ``</tag>`` is different? (in your case obviously ``div`` instead of ``tag``)

Comment: there is no difference

Comment: Which string is different? Could you update the question with an example of a tag you want to find and one you do not want to find?

Comment: can u explain how to use CSS Selector in my code?

Comment: see the [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) section in the documentation.  If you then have a specific question _about_ CSS selectors, you may want to ask that. Before anyone starts learning CSS just for this I'd like to quote: "All this CSS selector stuff is a convenience for people who already know the CSS selector syntax". If you find out they don't really solve your problem, update the question to explain what exactly you want, possibly with examples

Comment: I want to get one specific tag but every time i run code i get different result is there any different way to navigate tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Every time i run code i am getting different output.**

Yes. Every time the page is returning different results. Even if your selection is wrong that does not explain you getting different result printed every time. I ran this for a couple of times and got different results every time.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
r = requests.get("https://taripebi.ge/%E1%83%91%E1%83%94%E1%83%9C%E1%83%96%E1%83%98%E1%83%9C%E1%83%98%E1%83%A1-%E1%83%A4%E1%83%90%E1%83%A1%E1%83%94%E1%83%91%E1%83%98")
df=pd.read_html(r.text)
print(df)
```

Outputs

Run No. 1

```
[    0       1       2       3       4       5        6      7
0 NaN   ---00  2.4992  2.5700    2.64    2.63  2.59100  ---00
1 NaN   ---00  2.3593  2.4800    2.58   ---00     2.53  ---00
2 NaN   ---00  2.0493  2.2495   ---00  2.0500   2.2400  ---00
3 NaN   ---00  2.4300  2.5300    2.63  2.4510     2.58  ---00
4 NaN  2.3593  2.4100  2.4900  2.6300  2.4910     2.59  ---00
5 NaN   ---00  2.1593  2.4295   ---00  2.2010   2.4500  ---00
6 NaN  2.0400  2.1493  2.2495   ---00    2.05    ---00   2.24]
```

Run No 2

```
[    0       1       2       3       4       5        6      7
0 NaN   ---00  2.3593  2.4800    2.58   ---00     2.53  ---00
1 NaN   ---00  2.4300  2.5300    2.63  2.4510     2.58  ---00
2 NaN   ---00  2.1593  2.4295   ---00  2.2010   2.4500  ---00
3 NaN  2.3593  2.4100  2.4900  2.6300  2.4910     2.59  ---00
4 NaN  2.0400  2.1493  2.2495   ---00    2.05    ---00   2.24
5 NaN   ---00  2.4992  2.5700    2.64    2.63  2.59100  ---00
6 NaN   ---00  2.0493  2.2495   ---00  2.0500   2.2400  ---00]
```

Ideally as per your code you should be getting a result of `2.41` every time you run your code (given in the question).

[image]

What happens is that this page does some javascript authorization in the background and only then populates the valid data.

For these types of pages it is better to use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://taripebi.ge/%E1%83%91%E1%83%94%E1%83%9C%E1%83%96%E1%83%98%E1%83%9C%E1%83%98%E1%83%A1-%E1%83%A4%E1%83%90%E1%83%A1%E1%83%94%E1%83%91%E1%83%98')
source = driver.page_source
soup =BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
for paragraph in soup.find('div', style = "width: 40%;/* float: left; */"):
    print(paragraph)
```

Output

Run No 1

```
2.41
```

Run No 2

```
2.41
```